# Can PEiD deal with hard coded software limitations?

Tags: portable-executable

As we know [PEiD](http://www.peid.info/) can detect most common packers, cryptors and compilers for PE files, but can it detect the hard coded stuff(not by 3rd party packers,etc),like software usage date limitation?

Comment: Do you want to put something in your own product or want to crack something? If second motive then please this is not a warez forum.

Answer (score 0):

Well, protection "is a feature, not a bug". PEiD has some chance to start barking in heuristic mode if too much "strange code" is detected; however, IDA Pro has even more.